# NEED website to close when FB link is clicked

Tags: target, facebook-iframe, facebook-likebox

i have a website where there is a radio ad being played - and a FB "like" box - if someone clicks on a video within the FB stream it goes to FB and the website with the radio ad keeps playing.  I NEED to figure out how to make the website close.

I am a graphic designer, not a web expert - but i try, please don't bash me for not knowing the correct lingo.  I use adobe dreamweaver and am aware of the "target" preference but that only applies to something that is linked.. OH I'm using IFrame when asking for the code in FB for the like box.  please please help me!